# Deserialize XML element with attributes with no value using Jackson Java

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind, jackson-dataformat-xml

I am trying to deserialize the following XML and I couldn't get the parameter param section deserialized.

```
<video src="https://google.com/sample.mp4">
    <param>s</param>
    <param>Y</param>
    <param>Z</param>
</video>
```

My model

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlElementWrapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlProperty;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Video {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private String src;

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "param", useWrapping = false)
    private List<String> param = new ArrayList<>();

    public String getSrc() {
        return src;
    }

    public List<String> getParam() {
        return param;
    }

    public void setParam(List<String> param) {
        this.param = param;
    }
}
```

Output

```
{
    "src": "https://google.com/sample.mp4",
    "param": [
        "Z"
    ]
}
```

I am expecting the values of param to be something like

```
{
    "src": "https://google.com/sample.mp4",
    "param": [
        "s",
        "Y",
        "Z"
    ]
}
```

Java code

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new XmlFactory());
mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);
Video video = mapper.readValue(s, Video.class);
System.out.println(new ObjectMapper(new JsonFactory()).writeValueAsString(video));
```

Can someone help me getting it working. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following code and it worked for me,

```
XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
    mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);
    Video video = mapper.readValue(s, Video.class);
    System.out.println(new ObjectMapper(new JsonFactory()).writeValueAsString(video));
```

`XmlMapper` is frorm package `com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper`

Hope it helped you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use:

```
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "param")
@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
private List<String> param = new ArrayList<>();
```

and delete `mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);` as it only masks the issue.

This code worked for me:

```
XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
Video video = mapper.readValue(s, Video.class);
System.out.println(new ObjectMapper(new JsonFactory()).writeValueAsString(video));
```

Outputs:
    {"src":"https://google.com/sample.mp4","param":["s","Y","Z"]}